# EmberJS nested subroute custom index path not working as expected

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm following [one of the Ember Guides on routing](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/tutorial/subroutes/#toc_generating-a-nested-index-route) (v2.14.0) and I'm trying to set up a nested sub-route where the index route should redirect to a different subroute.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('dashboard', function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '/dashboard/calendar'});
    // ^should direct all dashboard index requests to dashboard/calendar right?
    // setting path = '/calendar' also doesn't work

    this.route('calendar');
    this.route('daily-journal');
  });
});
```

However when I load up `http://localhost:3000/dashboard`, I get this error:
[image]

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Show the `link-to`?

Comment: I didn't use `link-to`, I directly put `localhost:3000/dashboard` in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect to another route / from the dashboard - you can use the redirect from the route: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/redirection/

You would just put something in your dashboard index route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel() {
    this.transitionTo('dashboard.calendar');
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems this makes the dashboard index and all sub-routes (for me both `dashboard/calls` and `dashboard/calendar`) redirect to `dashboard/calendar` :( is there a way to limit this so that only `dashboard` (index route) redirects?

Comment: If you put this in the route file for the dashboard.index explicitly -